# Sorting nested objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, javascript-objects, nested-object

I am trying to sort object of objects obj in javascript on the basis of cummulativeSite in descending order through object.keys but it is not getting sorted.Please suggest a good approach or a method for the same to sort this.

```
var obj={


 B.E:{
    A: {percentgsite: 8.5, backlogenclsite: 8.5, regularenclsite: 3.5, cummulativeSite: 20.5},
    B: {percentgsite: 5.9, backlogenclsite: 5.9, regularenclsite: 8.5, cummulativeSite: 20.3},
    C: {percentgsite: 5.9, backlogenclsite: 6.4, regularenclsite: 8.9, cummulativeSite: 21.200000000000003}
    },



 Diploma:{
    A: {percentgsite: 8.5, cummulativeSite: 5.2},
    B: {percentgsite: 5.9, cummulativeSite: 8.5},
    C: {percentgsite: 5.9, cummulativeSite: 5.6}
    },



 M.E:{
    A: {percentgsite: 8.5, cummulativeSite: 11.9},
    B: {percentgsite: 5.9, cummulativeSite: 12.9},
    C: {percentgsite: 5.9, cummulativeSite: 13.5}
    }
}
```

Expected Output :

```
var obj={


 B.E:{

    C: {percentgsite: 5.9, backlogenclsite: 6.4, regularenclsite: 8.9, cummulativeSite: 21.200000000000003},
    A: {percentgsite: 8.5, backlogenclsite: 8.5, regularenclsite: 3.5, cummulativeSite: 20.5},
    B: {percentgsite: 5.9, backlogenclsite: 5.9, regularenclsite: 8.5, cummulativeSite: 20.3}
    },



 Diploma:{
    B: {percentgsite: 8.5, cummulativeSite: 8.5},
    C: {percentgsite: 5.9, cummulativeSite: 5.6},
    A: {percentgsite: 5.9, cummulativeSite: 5.2}
    },



 M.E:{
    C: {percentgsite: 8.5, cummulativeSite: 13.5},
    B: {percentgsite: 5.9, cummulativeSite: 12.9},
    A: {percentgsite: 5.9, cummulativeSite: 11.9}
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not a valid array. Is `arr` an array or an object with `B.E`, `Diploma` and `M.E` as keys?

Comment: I suppose B.E, Diploma and M.E are independent arrays, am I correct?

Comment: @adiga it's an object

Comment: @WagnerdeAndradePerin they are objects

Comment: @Kris Object don't guaranty  order, so you B.E, M.E needs to be array if you want order

Comment: @CodeManiac if i turn B.E, M.E, Diploma into array then how shall i proceed in their ordering

Comment: @Kris than you can sort them using `sort`, but are the keys `A,B,C` are necessary or useful to you ?

Comment: @CodeManiac yes these keys are to be retained i am using these keys later in my code to display data.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in comments you're ok to change `B.E` and so on to array ( Because object doesn't guaranty order ). So i will change them in array and than sort them based on `cummulativeSite` property

```js
var obj={'B.E':[{A:{percentgsite:8.5,backlogenclsite:8.5,regularenclsite:3.5,cummulativeSite:20.5}},{B:{percentgsite:5.9,backlogenclsite:5.9,regularenclsite:8.5,cummulativeSite:20.3}},{C:{percentgsite:5.9,backlogenclsite:6.4,regularenclsite:8.9,cummulativeSite:21.200000000000003}}],Diploma:[{A:{percentgsite:8.5,cummulativeSite:5.2}},{B:{percentgsite:5.9,cummulativeSite:8.5}},{C:{percentgsite:5.9,cummulativeSite:5.6}}],'M.E':[{A:{percentgsite:8.5,cummulativeSite:11.9}},{B:{percentgsite:5.9,cummulativeSite:12.9}},{C:{percentgsite:5.9,cummulativeSite:13.5}}]}

Object.keys(obj).forEach(e => {
  obj[e].sort( (a,b) =>{
   return Object.values(a)[0].cummulativeSite -
   Object.values(b)[0].cummulativeSite
   })
})

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: var obj={ B.E:[ 0:{ A: {percentgsite: 8.5, backlogenclsite: 8.5, regularenclsite: 3.5, cummulativeSite: 20.5}, B: {percentgsite: 5.9, backlogenclsite: 5.9, regularenclsite: 8.5, cummulativeSite: 20.3}; C: {percentgsite: 5.9, backlogenclsite: 6.4, regularenclsite: 8.9, cummulativeSite: 21.200000000000003} } ],    @Code Maniac   i am getting my B.E array in this format. Can you please suggest sorting now

Comment: @Kris your posted one doesn't seems to be valid  one `{ B.E: [ 0:`

Comment: this 0 is the index at which array is present  @Code Maniac

Answer (score 0):

You could use a nested [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like this:

```js
var obj={"B.E":{A:{percentgsite:8.5,backlogenclsite:8.5,regularenclsite:3.5,cummulativeSite:20.5},B:{percentgsite:5.9,backlogenclsite:5.9,regularenclsite:8.5,cummulativeSite:20.3},C:{percentgsite:5.9,backlogenclsite:6.4,regularenclsite:8.9,cummulativeSite:21.200000000000003}},"Diploma":{A:{percentgsite:8.5,cummulativeSite:5.2},B:{percentgsite:5.9,cummulativeSite:8.5},C:{percentgsite:5.9,cummulativeSite:5.6}},"M.E":{A:{percentgsite:8.5,cummulativeSite:11.9},B:{percentgsite:5.9,cummulativeSite:12.9},C:{percentgsite:5.9,cummulativeSite:13.5}}}

const sortedObj = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [dept, v]) =>{
  const sortedDept = Object.entries(v)
             .sort(([k1,v1], [k2,v2]) => v2.cummulativeSite - v1.cummulativeSite)
             .reduce((r, [k,v]) => (r[k] = v, r), {});
  
  acc[dept] = sortedDept;
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(sortedObj)
```

Forgot to mention that, [properties order in objects is not guaranteed in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/3082296), especially if you have integer `keys`. If you decide to change the inner items to an array, you get the idea.

Comment: if i take B.E, Diploma and M.E as an array inside this object will that suffice @adiga

Comment: @Kris how are you planning on converting "B.E" to an array? Will the structure be  `"B.E": [ { "A": { percentgsite } }, { "B": { percentgsite } } ]` OR `"B.E": [ { percentgsite}, { percentgsite} ]`

Comment: this is the format when i change it into array can i implement the way you suggested to get the sorting done in this case..  @adiga

Comment: var obj={

 B.E:[
  0:{
    A: {percentgsite: 8.5, backlogenclsite: 8.5, regularenclsite: 3.5, cummulativeSite: 20.5},
    B: {percentgsite: 5.9, backlogenclsite: 5.9, regularenclsite: 8.5, cummulativeSite: 20.3};
 C: {percentgsite: 5.9, backlogenclsite: 6.4, regularenclsite: 8.9, cummulativeSite: 21.200000000000003}
    }
  ],

@adiga